# Change the custom property value by pressing a key

Tags: python, rigid-body-simulation, shortcut

I have a rigid body car that I want to control by pressing the appropriate buttons (as in video games). I'm not very good at programming, and I don't have many ideas how to implement it. The car is controlled by drivers responsible for movement and steering, tied to custom properties respectively (they are shown in the picture). One of the ideas was to bind the keys to these settings in order to dynamically change them. For example, create a shortcut to the f7 button that executes a similar code "bpy.data.objects["Car"]["Acceleration"] += 1", and when you click f7, the car would start moving at a speed of 1. I tried it but I doubt that it's possible to execute such code in keybinding menu. Is it possible to implement something like this in a blender, or maybe there are better ideas how to create a car control with keys?(Do not offer to install unreal engine or something pls)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can bind operators to keyboard hotkeys in Blender. So you will probably need to learn to code your own operators. You can see examples in the Text Editor's Templates -> Python menu:

[image]

Modal operators can keep running and changing stuff while in operation as well as react to input events, so you might be more interested in them. See [the documantation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Operator.html).